# Mongo DB C++ bad format decimal, add ".0" to end, at converter to JSON

Tags: c++, json, mongodb

When I add decimal numbers (float or double) on mongo object and after convert to JSON, the converter change "." by ","  add ".0" to end of each number.

```
float x = 2.3;
float y = 2.0;

mongo::BSONObj obj = BSON("x" << x << "y" << y);

std::string json = obj.toString();

// {"x":2,3.0, "y": 2,0.0}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The bad format. Should be: {"x":2.3, "y": 2.0}

Comment: While I (and most other people) know what your intended question is, you don't actually *ask* a question, rather you just state a fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I should use "jsonString()" instead of "toString()"

```
float x = 2.3;
float y = 2.0;

mongo::BSONObj obj = BSON("x" << x << "y" << y);

std::string json = obj.jsonString();
```